# Determine if Call to Action is from a View

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper

Is there a way to determine if a call to a controllers action is from a view using the Html.RenderAction function.

This is similar to Request.IsAjaxRequest.  If the call comes from a view I would like to just render a partial view rather than the the full view with master page.

BTW Render partial is not a viable solution as the action fetches additional data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the ControllerContext.IsChildAction has the given effect.  this way I can provide the same HTML using a child action and a ajax request (for fallback on non javascript users)

```
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() || ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
            return PartialView("ViewName", results);
```

Comment: thanks for this question and answer it is useful, I needed to check this in a view so I used ViewContext.IsChildAction